# Jquery click bindings are not working correctly when binding multiple copies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cloning

I seem to have an issue when creating copies of a template and tying the .click() method to them properly.  Take the following javascript for example:

```
function TestMethod() {
    var test = Array();
    test[0] = 0;
    test[1] = 1;
    test[2] = 2;

    // Insert link into the page
    $("#test_div").html("<a href=\"#\"></a><br>");
    var list;
    for (x = 0; x < test.length; x++) {
        var temp = $("#test_div").clone();
        temp.find('a').html("Item #" + test[x]);
        temp.click(function () { alert(x); });

        if (list == undefined)
            list = temp;
        else
            list = list.append(temp.contents());
    }
    $("#test_div2").append(list);
 }
```

The problem I am seeing with this is that no matter which item the user clicks on, it always runs alert(2), even when you click on the first few items.

How can I get this to work?

**Edit:** I have made a very simple example that should show the problem much clearer.  No matter what item you click on, it always shows an alert box with the number 2 on it.

Comment: `for (x = 0; x < objects.length; x++) {`, what is `objects`?

Comment: fixed it.  it's the var objects = data.objects; (data is the json structure passed by $.ajax)

Comment: I got another solution... please read my answer again... :) cheers!

Comment: Both solutions worked, but I opted to mark Reigel as the answer only because I opted to not use the Jquery.Each() and just use the bind() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, `.valueOf()` in JS returns the primitive value of a Boolean object.....

this would not happen `ShowObject(5,'T');`... `ShowObject(objectVal.valueOf(), 'T');`

why not use `objects[x].Value` directly? `ShowObject(objects[x].Value, 'T');`

**WOOOOOSSSHHHH!**

after searching deeply... I found a solution...

because it's a closure, it won't really work that way...
here's a solution,

```
temp.find('a').bind('click', {testVal: x},function (e) { 
   alert(e.data.testVal);
   return false;
});
```

for best explanation, [please read this](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)... in the middle part of the page where it says ***Passing Event Data*** 
 [a quick demo of above code](http://jsbin.com/ivofu3)

Comment: I tried objectVal, objectVal.ValueOf(), etc..  It all seems to produce the same result, only the last objectVal value is used for all of the cloned objects.

Comment: is there a difference between `objects[x].Value` and `objects[x].Text` in your codes?

Comment: Yes, value returns my Id number and Text returns the name of the object.  Both are being read correctly (tested in Chrome's debugger)

Comment: Ah I see, I knew there had to be a better way to pass the value in, I just didn't know I could do it that way!

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue arises from a misunderstanding of scopes in JavaScript. (My apologies if I'm wrong.)

```
function () {
    for (...) {
        var foo = ...;

        $('<div>').click(function () { alert(foo); }).appendTo(...);
    }
}
```

In JavaScript, **only functions create a new scope** (commonly referred to as a **closure**).

So, every round of the `for` loop will know the same `foo`, since its scope is the `function`, not the `for`. This also applies to the events being defined. By the end of looping, every `click` will know the same `foo` and know it to be the last value it was assigned.

To get around this, either create an inner closure with an immediately-executing, anonymous function:

```
function () {
    for (...) {
        (function (foo) {
            $('<div>').click(function () { alert(foo); }).appendTo(...);
        })(...);
    }
}
```

Or, using a callback-based function, such as [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
function () {
    $.each(..., function (i, foo) {
        $('<div>').click(function () { alert(foo); }).appendTo(...);
    });
}
```

---

For your issue, I'd go with the latter (note the changes of `objects[x]` to just `object`):

```
var list;
jQuery.each(data.objects, function (x, object) {

    // Clone the object list item template
    var item = $("#object_item_list_template").clone();

    // Setup the click action and inner text for the link tag in the template
    var objectVal = object.Value;
    item.find('a').click(function () { ShowObject(objectVal.valueOf(), 'T'); }).html(object.Text);

    // add the html to the list
    if (list == undefined)
        list = item;
    else
        list.append(item.contents());
});
```

Comment: Ok this makes a lot of sense!  I will try this when I get home from work, thanks!